# Not able to retrieve data from apex class using lwc

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components

I am learning lwc and got stuck in the getting data from Apex class. Below is the code

JS:

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
import getAccountList from '@salesforce/apex/AccountController.getAccountList';

export default class AccountComponent extends LightningElement {
    accounts;
    error;

    handleLoad() {
        getAccountList()
            .then((result) => {                
                alert(JSON.stringify(result));
                this.accounts = result;
                this.error = undefined;
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                alert(JSON.stringify(error));
                this.error = error;
                this.accounts = undefined;
            });
    }
}
```

Apex Class:

```
public with sharing class AccountController {
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static List<Account> getAccountList() {
        return [SELECT Id, Name FROM Account WITH SECURITY_ENFORCED LIMIT 10];
    }    
}
```

I am getting below error in an alert box:

> {"ok":false,"status":400,"statusText":"Bad Request","body":{}}

But in Chrome->Network tab, I am getting 500 Internal server error with below message:

> error parsing apex response: Unexpected token * in JSON at position 0

[image]

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I tried your code and it works for me. can you see in the developer console if you don't have an error?

Comment: Can you add the Apex debug logs?

Comment: @rahulgawale They're apparently using a Local Development Server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're using the Local Development Server. This feature requires a Scratch Org in order to run Apex. Make sure you've started the Local Development Server, created a Scratch Org, and pushed the source code to the server in order to run the code. Alternatively, deploy this code to an org so you can run it in a Salesforce environment. Please note the limitations of the [Local Development Server](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.get_started_local_dev_modules).